# Attempt to read property "up_title" on null (View: C:\wamp64\www\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

i was working with laravel 8 and php 7 and there is a simple block of code in my view like below :

```
<h6 class="mt-3">{{$specialNews->up_title}}</h6>
```

now i updated my php to version 8 and when i hit the route i get this error :

```
Attempt to read property "up_title" on null (View: C:\wamp64\www\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

before that it was null safe it self . now the number of these variables are alot like 100 and i dont want to null safe all with `?? null` is there any way to skip this error and is it because of php 8 ??

Comment: first check the variable in balde via ```{{dd($specialNews)}}```

Comment: i think error occur because your controller return a null value for the ```specialNews```

Answer (score 1):

To skip this error on PHP 8, use null-safe property operator `?->`.

```
<h6 class="mt-3">{{$specialNews?->up_title}}</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this: `{{$specialNews ? $specialNews->up_title : ''}}`